# при попытке установки NetfilterQueue все почти устанавливается вроде, но вот что выдает

Tags: pip

```
Collecting NetfilterQueue
  Using cached NetfilterQueue-1.0.0.tar.gz (87 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: NetfilterQueue
  Building wheel for NetfilterQueue (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for NetfilterQueue (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [30 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/netfilterqueue
      copying netfilterqueue/_version.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/netfilterqueue
      copying netfilterqueue/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/netfilterqueue
      running egg_info
      writing NetfilterQueue.egg-info/PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to NetfilterQueue.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
      writing top-level names to NetfilterQueue.egg-info/top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'NetfilterQueue.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      adding license file 'LICENSE.txt'
      writing manifest file 'NetfilterQueue.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      copying netfilterqueue/_impl.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/netfilterqueue
      copying netfilterqueue/_impl.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/netfilterqueue
      copying netfilterqueue/_impl.pyx -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/netfilterqueue
      copying netfilterqueue/py.typed -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/netfilterqueue
      running build_ext
      building 'netfilterqueue._impl' extension
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9/netfilterqueue
      x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.9 -c netfilterqueue/_impl.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9/netfilterqueue/_impl.o
      netfilterqueue/_impl.c:707:10: fatal error: libnfnetlink/linux_nfnetlink.h: Нет такого файла или каталога
        707 | #include "libnfnetlink/linux_nfnetlink.h"
            |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      compilation terminated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for NetfilterQueue
Failed to build NetfilterQueue
ERROR: Could not build wheels for NetfilterQueue, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

У меня такая же сложность как у тебя точь в точь, мне помогло:

```
sudo apt install libnfnetlink-dev libnetfilter-queue-dev

pip3 install netfilterqueue
```

и все норм работает